# R: Logistic Regression with different loss function

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I’ve seen some papers that present the idea of training classifiers such as logistic regression that are really meant to optimize a custom cost model (such as by maximizing profit given expect revenues for predictions depending on whether they are false positives, true negatives, true positives, or true negatives) not by optimizing the typical log-loss function and then looking for the optimal decision cut-off threshold, but by using different loss functions that weight differently the costs of each classification type or of each misclassification type (although I've seen that different authors propose different functions), and these seem to provide better results when evaluating them based on the customly-defined cost function.

I was wondering if there are any implementations of such methods in R. Particularly, I'd like to try fitting a logistic regression treating the cost of misclassifying as false positive to be a multiple of the cost of misclassifying as false negative. I found a package that does just this for decision trees (although in that case it's based on the class proportions on the leaves rather than something like log-loss) and I see that there are some options for observation-specific weights in logistic regression, but not for error type weights.

Comment: You ought to pose a specific case. Responding to a change in the cost function probably just involves shifting the cutpoint on the linear predictor scale. Unfortunately this Q is on the cusp of being closed because people think you are asking for us to recommend a package. I suspect no "package" is needed beyond the standard "stats" package.

Comment: Ok, here's an example with a neural network: 
http://www.researchgate.net/publication/236622378_Making_Accurate_Credit_Risk_Predictions_with_Cost-Sensitive_MLP_Neural_Networks